# Who is the 9th Titan shifter?

Tags: attack-on-titan

**SPOILERS**

Read **only** if you are caught up to date with the latest manga chapter (93 in this case).

Before chapter 93 we knew

> that the 9 titan shifters are :
>  1) Progenitor Titan aka Founding Titan -> Currently Eren Jaeger
>  2) Attack Titan aka Assault Titan -> Currently Eren Jaeger
>  3) Colossal Titan -> Currently Armin Arlert 
>  4) Female Titan -> Currently Annie Leonheart
>  5) Armored Titan -> Currently Reiner Braun
>  6) Beast Titan -> Currently Zeke Jaeger
>  7) Cart Titan aka Mule Titan aka Quadrupedal Titan -> Peak
>  8) Dancing Titan -> Ymir
>  9) Jaw Titan -> Galliard

After reading chapter 93, interestingly we have:

> that the 9 titan shifters are :
>  1) Progenitor Titan aka Founding Titan -> Currently Eren Jaeger
>  2) Attack Titan aka Assault Titan -> Currently Eren Jaeger
>  3) Colossal Titan -> Currently Armin Arlert 
>  4) Female Titan -> Currently Annie Leonheart
>  5) Armored Titan -> Currently Reiner Braun
>  6) Beast Titan -> Currently Zeke Jaeger
>  7) Cart Titan aka Mule Titan aka Quadrupedal Titan -> Peak
>  8) Dancing Titan aka Jaw Titan (are the same!!) -> Currently Galliard
>  9) ?????????

Are there any hints so far?

Comment: I havent read the manga, I have only seen the anime and read a wikia, but isnt Bertolt supposed to be the one you mention to belong to Armin?

Comment: @Pablo please do not read spoilers. It is not worth it. Try reading the manga and everything will make sense :) I am sorry for spoiling.

Comment: I thought the 9th Titan was Galliards brother who was sent with Reiner en Bertholdt to Paradis Island and got eaten there by Ymir. From that point on Ymir was able to shift between her titan form and human form after wandering as a titan for over 60 years.

Comment: SPOILERS!! >! Yes we all thought so too, but Galliard ate Ymir, which either means that Galliard has two titan powers, or that he has the same titan as Ymir, which in turn means that the 9th titan is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Attack on Titan, **Chapter 95**, pages 16-17 we find out that the 9th Titan-Shifter is the

> War Hammer Titan, which is currently in possession of the Tybur family who currently resides in Marley. We also find out that the War Hammer titan is not used for warfare and has never been used against any enemy state (of Marley). It is important to note that the Tybur family was the first family of titan-shifters to rebel against King Fritz in the Great Titan War and they carry a lot of political clout. [image]

In **Chapter 101**, the identity of the 9th Titan-Shifter was revealed to be

> Willy Tybur's [sister](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Willy%27s_sister). [image]

Comment: Yeah I read it a couple of days ago. I will pick this as the answer

Answer (score 2):

People seem to be forgetting something...after the great Titan war Marley had a total of 7 titans and the ones behind the walls had 2

Grisha Jaeger brought the attack titan from marely leaving marley with 6 titans  the six being Jaws Titan, Cart Titan, Colossal Titan, Female Titan, Armored titan, Beast Titan...

The Ninth Titan should be with the Eldians behind the walls which means someone behind the walls knows who or what it is and hasn't said yet

Comment: +1 because you are right, and I do agree with that. There's a theory actually that I recently read, but it's going to be a gigantic spoiler so I'm keeping my mouth shut

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screencap]

The 9th titan Is actually a winged titan. It makes sense if you consider the Marley downfall right now is how they can only rely on titans on land and their forces are weakening because of that. Yet the 9th titan is residing inside the Paradis walls.

Answer (score 0):

All we have is Galliard saying that he did this to become "Jaws" by eating "Dancing" Ymir and that Reiner was very brotherly like and someone the team can count on. I think it is a lie. They would not just unceremoniously kill Ymir off-screen and also cause a serious plot hole of consuming a Titan shifter makes you become an entirely different type of Titan shifter.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Anime and Manga SE. Adding sources (Chapters, Wikia etc.) which check out helps improve quality of the answer. You can use spoilers to set a bit of context for your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

i think the 9th titan is flying and is hidden somewhere near the paradise island. to back it up, marleyans are having problems since all of the ships that went to paradise island in all those years, none came back. also, there is their statement that they need a flying sort of battle artillery so they can just bombard their enemies from atop.